# I cannot get my pyramid class to print the pyramid

Tags: java

I am attempting to print a numbers pyramid, however I cannot figure out what this error means, or how to fix it.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pyramid pmid = new pyramid();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many rows do you want in your pyramid: 1-10? ");
        int numRows = in.nextInt();
        if (numRows < 1 || numRows > 10){
            System.out.println("ERROR: Number must be greater than zero and less than 11");
            System.exit(0);
        }


    }
}
```

```
package com.company;

public class pyramid {
    private int numRow;

    public pyramid(int numRow){
        //this.rows=rows;
        this.numRow=numRow;

        //make three different triangles...
        for(int i=1; i<=numRow; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<=(numRow-i)*2;j++){
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            for (int k=i;k>=1;k--) {
                System.out.println(" " + k);
            }
            for(int l=2; l<=i;l++){
                System.out.println(" "+l);
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the error I am getting, along with many others when I attempt to fix it.

```
:6:24
java: constructor pyramid in class com.company.pyramid cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: You have defined your constructor as `public pyramid(int numRow)`, but call it as `pyramid()`. Can you spot the missing argument? NB. Class names in Java are usually written in PascalCase, i.e. they start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: This is a common mistake; when you create a constructor (without overloading) with parameters and you create an object of the class, you must include the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I am not quite sure what "overloading" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, your Constructor in Pyramid takes the number of rows you want to print as argument. Yet in your original code you call `pyramid()` without argument. Try calling the pyramid method with the `numRows` from Scanner as argument.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many rows do you want in your pyramid: 1-10? ");
    int numRows = in.nextInt();
    if (numRows < 1 || numRows > 10){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Number must be greater than zero and less than 11");
        System.exit(0);
    } else {
        pyramid pmid = new pyramid(numRows);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: This makes so much sense. I tried reading other posts on here with the same problem and could not understand the answers, but you made it easy to understand. Thank you so much.